# Unable to get inject entityManager using @PersistenceContext

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was trying to make property based multiple database configuration using spring boot and jpa using hibernate as provider . I had this EntityManagerBuider which was being called by a configuration class .**getEntityManagerFactory** was being called by the client class .

```
public class EntityManagerBuilder  {

    private static String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN="packagesToScan";

    private static String PERSISTANT_UNIT_NAME="persistence.unit.name";

    private static String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_CONSTANT="hibernate.dialect";

    private static String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_DEFAULT_VALUE="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL";

    private static String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_CONSTANT="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    private static String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_DEFAULT_VALUE="none";

    private static Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityManagerBuilder.class);

    public EntityManagerBuilder(){

    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                =new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                               Map<String,String> jpaProperties,
                                                               Map<String,String> jpaEntityInfo,
                                                               String transaction,
                                                               ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory){

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
                =new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        properties.putAll(jpaProperties);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(getVendorAdaptor());
        if(jpaEntityInfo==null || jpaEntityInfo.get(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN)==null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Packages to scan required in jpa configuration ");
        }
        if(jpaProperties.get(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_CONSTANT)==null){
            logger.warn("Hibernate dialect not set choosing default as null");
            jpaProperties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_CONSTANT, HIBERNATE_DIALECT_DEFAULT_VALUE);
        }
        if(jpaProperties.get(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_CONSTANT)==null){
            logger.warn("Hibernate HB2DDL not set choosing mysql as default");
            jpaProperties.put(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_CONSTANT, HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_DEFAULT_VALUE);
        }
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(jpaEntityInfo.get(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("perisisted");
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
//registering spring bean object 
        configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(transaction, localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject());
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();

    }

    private static HibernateJpaVendorAdapter getVendorAdaptor() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }
}
```

The problem which I am having is , I am unable to inject entity manager from persistence context .Spring beans are not configured by the time persistence context is injected . The configuration code of spring container never gets executed , instead it start injecting jpa context persistence context before spring context .

```
@Repository
public class BooksDao  {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManageModuleAware entityManageModuleAware;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persisted")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


}
```

And thus I encounter this error everytime I run the application

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

**A component required a bean named 'persisted' that could not be found.**
```

Is there any way spring beans are configured before **persistence context is injected** . 
I want to use @Transactional with multiple datasource configured . So was thinking of creating entitymanagerfactory beans , with their respective persistence unit names , and thought I would get persistence context at Dao level .

I also made Transactional  beans :-

```
public  static void setTransactionBean(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory , DataSource dataSource,
                                                  String transactionName){
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        ConfigurableBeanFactory configurableBeanFactory=(ConfigurableBeanFactory)beanFactoryStatic;
        configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton(transactionName, jpaTransactionManager);
    }
```

Comment: You don't show the whole code. That's why it is hard to understand what are you doing. By the way, why are you configuring it programmatically, not via configuration file?

Comment: You have to show from where you are calling these static methods, as suggested by mentallurg , you should use Bean by using Configuration, even if you want custom properties use @Value